# How to know which column's value is changed in CDC

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, change-data-capture

I am using CDC feature in sql 2012 and lets suppose i have a table name as `Employee` and also have some records in it . Suppose someone changed `Last Name` in employee's table . Then there goes 2 entries in `CDC` table , have both records before change and after change . I want to know that which column is changed .

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166250/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Change-Data-Capture-CDC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is column tracking. You'll need to utilize the CHANGETABLE function to get what you want.

Column tracking information appears in the SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS column that is returned by the CHANGETABLE(CHANGES …) function.

Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933874(v=sql.110%29.aspx%23Obtain) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

A better option.  This how to tell if the LastName value has changed using a CDC function

```
        SELECT 
        sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(x.__$start_lsn) AS ChangeDateTime
    ,   x.__$start_lsn
    ,   x.__$operation
    ,   x.__$update_mask
    ,   x.YourPrimaryKeyColumn
    ,   x.LastName
    ,   sys.fn_cdc_has_column_changed ('YourCDCInstanceName', 'LastName', x.__$update_mask) LastNameHasChanged
    FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_YourCDCInstanceName(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all') x
```

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-cdc-has-column-changed-transact-sql) for more info.

Comment: Posting links to other resources is encouraged, but you should also include information in your post about relevant information (that explains _why_ this is the right answer) from that external resource or otherwise. Please check out [This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/360627) to learn more about why this is generally frowned upon and can be considered off-topic.